# Show only product name in url Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.5

I have a url like this 
https://rockmobile.pk/detail/oneplus6
and want to remove word "detail" and show only product name like
https://rockmobile.pk/oneplus6.html . My .htaccess file in public folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^-]*).html$ detail/$1/  [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

The rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*).html$ detail/$1/  [L]
```

do detect /oneplus6.html but url changed to /detail/oneplus6

(tested it on localhost apache wampserver)

> http://localhost/projectName/public/oneplus6.html 
>   change to
>   http://localhost/projectName/public/detail/oneplus6

Comment: Hi Saad. I have provided the working solutionfor your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `[P]` from the rewrite rule so that it will proxy the request

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^-]*).html$ detail/$1/ [P]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: After removing [L] it throws the error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: Yes, when I go through "public/detail/oneplus6" it do show me the content

Comment: Ok. So you want rewrite but url should not be changed in the browser. Is it? In that case you should use [P] flag. Let me update my answer for the same

Comment: After updating to [P] tag it shows not found error, its something related to Laravel, I have tested my rewrite rule in simple files and it works fine, its not working with Laravel